# How to remove label incase column has only one item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, highcharts

I have stack highcharts, I want to hide label text if column has only one stack value.

In this case, I want to hide **Board** text in column.

[image]

I tried handle in `dataLabels` formatter, but with no success:

```
dataLabels: {
        formatter: function() {
          console.log(this);
          debugger;
          let countValue = this.series.userOptions.data.filter(x => x != 0).length;
          if(countValue <= 1){
             return '';
          }
          return this.series.name;
        },
```

This my source code

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/viethien/ak2h1sfq/11/

Thanks

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked column chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                textOutline: false,
                color: ( // theme
                    Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style &&
                    Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style.color
                ) || 'gray'
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'center',
        x: 0,
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        y: 5,
        
        backgroundColor:
            Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || 'white',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 0,
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        },
         series: {
      //stacking: 'normal',
      dataLabels: {
        formatter: function() {
          console.log(this);
          debugger;
          let countValue = this.series.userOptions.data.filter(x => x != 0).length;
          if(countValue <= 1){
             return '';
          }
          return this.series.name;
        },
        enabled: true,
        //allowOverlap: true,
        //align: 'right',
        color: '#444',
        textOutline: false,
        shadow: false,
        //x:-50,
        style: {
          fontSize: "8px",
          textShadow: "0px"
        }
      },
      //pointPadding: 0.1,
      pointWidth: 50,
      groupPadding: 0.2,
      stacking: 'normal',
      //colorByPoint: true,
      //showInLegend: false
    }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Component',
        data: [4, 7, 3],
        stack: 'Forecast'
    }, {
        name: 'Module',
        data: [3, 2, 2],
        stack: 'Forecast'
    },
    {
        name: 'Board',
        data: [5, 5, 3, 2],
        stack: 'Forecast'
    },
    {
        name: 'Component',
        data: [6, 4, 5, 8],
        stack: 'Real'
    }, {
        name: 'Module',
        data: [3, 3, 4, 3],
        stack: 'Real'
    },
    {
        name: 'Board',
        data: [4, 6, 6, 4],
        stack: 'Real'
    }
 ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `stackLabels: {enabled: false}`?

Comment: i have just tried, it is not work

Comment: Sorry! It's more complex than I thought. It looks like a stacked column and grouped at the same time. No series length is <= 1 when I looked the output in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the easiest solution is to compare the `this.y` to the the `this.point.stackTotal`. If the value is the same - hide text.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0ows79bm/

```
   formatter: function() {
      if(this.y === this.point.stackTotal) {
        return ''
      }
      return this.series.name;
    },
```

Comment: when data changed, this is my solution, I add more for condition if(this.y === this.point.stackTotal || this.y == 0) return '';

Comment: can you help me this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61317228/hide-categories-with-value-below-than-specific-value-highcharts

Comment: I answered with my proposal of solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare `y` with `total`, if they are equal then this column has only one stack. Something like:

```
formatter: function() {
  if(this.y == this.total){
    return '';
  }
  return this.series.name;
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o940dfxz/1/)

**Edit:** In case you pass 0 as value in your data, the condition would be `if(!this.y || this.y == this.total)...`

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unyj4pg6/)

Comment: I tried your solution, but it doesn't work in this data https://jsfiddle.net/viethien/zmdy0ejo/2/ can you help to check it?

Comment: In case of your second data, you need add more condition to check if y != 0 or not. So the final condition will be `if(!this.y || this.y == this.total)...`. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/unyj4pg6/

Comment: Perfect, Thanks Cường

Answer (score 0):

Your `dataLabels.formatter()` implementation is somehow wrong.

### Here's what's happening:

`this` returns an object with a `y value` for each stack on a bar-chart. Your target should be to know how the total for each bar-chart is summed up. So your best bet is to try to check if every data passed for each stack sums up to `y`. Here's an example:

[image]

From the picture above, I just used your code and `console.log(this)` inside `formatter()`. The pattern is pretty clear, you must bet of comparing each value of `y` to the entire total of the bar-chart stacks.

So doing `this.y == this.total` should tell you if the data, at that current instance actually sums up to make the entire total of the bar-chart stack. As you can se on the picture, where `y=2` the sum total of the stack for that bar is `2` so this would match our comparison `this.y == this.total`;

So you should just use instead.
`formatter: function(){ return this.y == this.total || this.y === 0 ? "" : this.series.name;}`

Comment: can you update your code in my current code https://jsfiddle.net/viethien/zmdy0ejo/2/